# cakephp checkbox is showing extra hidden field

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

```
foreach($apps as $app){


        echo $this->Form->input('Application', array('type'=>'checkbox', 'id'=>$app['Application']['description'], 'div'=>false,'type'=>'checkbox','value' => $app['Application']['description'],'label'=>$app['Application']['description']));



    }


<div class="checkboxes"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="data[Group][Application]" id="GG_" value="0"/><input type="checkbox" name="data[Group][Application]"  id="GG" value="GG"/><label for="GG">GG</label><input type="hidden" name="data[Group][Application]" id="BS_" value="0"/><input type="checkbox" name="data[Group][Application]"  id="BS" value="BS"/><label for="BS">BS</label>  <div>
</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="data[Group][Grant]" id="GroupGrant_" value="0"/><input type="checkbox" name="data[Group][Grant]"  style="float: left; display: inline" value="Edit Weather" id="GroupGrant"/><label for="GroupGrant">Edit Weather</label><input type="hidden" name="data[Group][Grant]" id="GroupGrant_" value="0"/><input type="checkbox" name="data[Group][Grant]"  style="float: left; display: inline" value="Edit Traffic" id="GroupGrant"/><label for="GroupGrant">Edit </label>       




        </div>
```

not sure where the hidden field is coming from.
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is a cake fallback in case you don't select the checkbox and post the form in order for the validation to jump in.
in this case php would not submit anything for this field (not even an empty string). therefore cake has found a smart workaround to overcome this issue.

similar thing with radio buttons btw.

Comment: when I hit submit, it just adds the last checkbox. I thought it could be because of this.

Answer (score 5):

Even though there is a hidden field we can make it disabled when we submit the form, so that it won't appear in the submitted data..
You need to write in the following way..

```
echo $this->Form->input('Application', array('type'=>'checkbox', 'id'=>$app['Application']['description'], 'div'=>false,'type'=>'checkbox','value' => $app['Application']['description'],'label'=>$app['Application']['description'],'hiddenField'=>false));
```

Comment: but that most likely breaks the workflow. I would not recommend that.

Comment: i like it how the `hiddenField` parameter, which is the key point of this answer, comes last