# cakephp checkbox multiple select just sends the value of last selected checkbox

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I am not getting the value of all the checkboxes selected. It just gives me the value of last selected checkbox

here is the code

```
foreach($apps as $app){


        echo $this->Form->input('Application.id', array('type'=>'checkbox','multiple' => 'checkbox' , 'id'=>$app['Application']['description'], 'div'=>false,'type'=>'checkbox','value' => $app['Application']['description'],'label'=>$app['Application']['description']));



    }
```

and on submit I get the very last checkbox which is LASTCHECKBOX

```
object(CakeRequest) {
    params => array(
        'plugin' => null,
        'controller' => 'groups',
        'action' => 'add',
        'named' => array(),
        'pass' => array()
    )
    data => array(

        'Application' => array(
            'id' => 'LASTCHECKBOX'
        )

    )
    query => array()
    url => 'groups/add'
    base => ''
    webroot => '/'
    here => '/groups/add'
}
```

Comment: Why the double post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049917/cakephp-checkbox-is-showing-extra-hidden-field

Comment: @mark They are actually separate questions related to a similar topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it is because of "value".

in your case use `"options" => array(1, 2, 3)`

you should better never set value, default or anything like that in the view.
use the controller action to set a default.
than it should work fine.

```
if ($this->request->isPost()) {

} else {
    $this->request->data['Model']['fieldname'] = 'defaultvalue';
}
```

Comment: well, if you are using a "multiple" checkbox then there must be several values to chose from. therefore you have an options array with multiple entries (and never a single value).

Answer (score 1):

For multiple checkboxes you need to have `[]` as the last part of the name HMTL attribute (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7880656/327074) for more explanation).

This is done in CakePHP using the 'select' type of input. If you look at the [Form Helper select documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::select) for 2.0 (but applies to v1.2+ as well) you don't need the loop you just need to create a multiple select using checkboxes:

```
<?php
$options = array(
    'Value 1' => 'Label 1',
    'Value 2' => 'Label 2'
);
echo $this->Form->select('Model.field', $options, array(
    'multiple' => 'checkbox'
));
?>
```

So I think for you you don't need the `foreach($apps` you need to modify $apps to be in in a similar format to `$options`.

```
<?php
$apps = array(
    'App Id 1' => 'Description 1',
    'App Id 2' => 'Description 2'
);
echo $this->Form->select('Application.id', $apps, array(
    'multiple' => 'checkbox'
));
?>
```

Should ouput:

```
<div class="input select">
   <label for="ApplicationId">Id</label>
   <input name="data[Application][id]" value="" id="ApplicationId" type="hidden">
   <div class="checkbox">
      <input name="data[Application][id][]" value="App Id 1" id="ApplicationId1" type="checkbox">
      <label for="ApplicationId1">Description 1</label>
   </div>
   <div class="checkbox">
      <input name="data[Application][id][]" value="App Id 2" id="ApplicationId2" type="checkbox">
      <label for="ApplicationId2">Description 2</label>
   </div>
</div>
```